# How can I find a local guide to take me safely up Mt Toubkal in Morocco?

Tags: morocco, guides, mountains, mountain-climbing

My partner and I will be visiting Morocco in late December and would like to hire a local and knowledgeable guide for climbing Mt Toubkal, who can also provide equipment (crampons, ice axe etc). Many of the sites I've found run longer tours (4-7 days) but we're only looking to do 2 days. I've heard you can just find guides when you arrive in the local town (Imlil) where the trek starts - but am not sure if this is true, or how to go about vetting their expertise.

Comment: Are you outgoing? At your hotel in Imlil you'll meet people coming and going from Mt Toubkal and other adventurous places in the Morocco highlands.  Nobody goes up there just to sit in the hotel.  You'll be able to ask them about their guide and how they got on with them.  You can also ask the concierge to make a referral.  Then invite prospective guides for coffee klatch in the hotel bar or restaurant  and lay out your objectives and then listen to what they say.

Comment: How would you vet the expertise of ones you find online, or through friends?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Local guide, yes, "can also provide equipment (crampons, ice axe etc)" astronomically unlikely, and no such eq is needed for the toubkal